# Why can't I move my circle inside the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to move two circles separately, but I can't seem to make the two circles move despite searching over w3school or youtube, I know how to move one circle but when I try to move two circle by creating a constructor it fails.

I'm sure this is a dumb question but I just can't help but ask.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let ball = new drawCircle(50, 50, 20);
let ballTwo = new drawCircle(100, 100, 20);
function drawCircle(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI *2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightskyblue";
        ctx.fill();
    }
    
}

function draw() {
    ball.x += 1;
    ball.draw();
    ballTwo.x += 1;
    ballTwo.draw();
    if (x + r > canvas.width || x < r) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if (y + r > canvas.width || y < r) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Círculo</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        #canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="/js/canvasTwo.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: It says the error right there. x is not defined in your second draw function in your if statements. Maybe you should reference the ball(s).

Comment: Thank youuuu!!! that was the problem, thanks for the help!